# add/edit/delete api, user update data overwrites data in DB nodejs express mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am writing an API that takes data and stores it into DB, also edits it and deletes it, the add/delete works fine, but when I update I want to be able to update only certain attributes, and if the user doesn't send an attribute I want the code to keep the data already in the DB. Instead if I don't send an attribute it's overwritten by empty data.

Here's an example:

```
router.post('/update', function (req, res) {



 var first_name = req.body.first_name,
last_name = req.body.last_name,
email = req.body.email,
phone_number = req.body.phone_number,
clas = req.body.clas,
subject = req.body.subject,
teacher_id = req.body.teacher_id;


    req.assert('teacher_id', 'Invalid teacher_id').notEmpty();
  var errors = req.validationErrors();
 if (errors) {
res.json(400, {success: false, message: "please enter your teacher_id  "});
return;
 }



 Teacher.findOne({_id: teacher_id}, function (err, teacher) {
if (err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {

    teacher.first_name = first_name != null || first_name
    != undefined ? first_name : teacher.first_name;

    teacher.last_name = last_name != null || last_name
    != undefined ? last_name : teacher.last_name;

    teacher.email = email != null || email
    != undefined ? email : teacher.email;

    teacher.phone_number = phone_number != null || phone_number
    != undefined ? phone_number : teacher.pickup_points;

    teacher.clas = clas != null || clas
    != undefined ? clas : teacher.clas;

    teacher.subject = subject != null && subject
    != undefined ? subject : teacher.subject;

    teacher.save(function (err, teacher) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {

            res.json({success: true, message: "teacher successfully updated"});
        }
    });

}
 });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

> This method is a little different from what you are doing but I'd recommend this way to you so that you can keep your document models in one place and call them whenever you need them. Validations part can be handled using a separate module which is for mongoose.

The way you are updating it expects other variables to be assigned as it is, like I am fetching the document using `findone` then `objectname.value` = `newobjectname.value`

A simple way to solve this would be using `findoneandupdate`.

```
modelname.findOneAndUpdate({
primarykey: primarykey
 }, {
$set: {
nameindocument: valuetobereplace
//you can add here values that you would like to change
}
}, {
new: true //new:true here helps to get updated object in return
}, function(err, doc) {
if (err) {
console.error("Error:" + err);
} else {
}
});
```

Comment: Mongoose won't fire it's validations on the model if you use this method, make sure you manually validate in this case.

Comment: @Paul I use one extra module to address to validations issue and put it to use while defining schema. What's wrong with that? Not worthy of a downvote, is it?!

Comment: It's worth mentioning in the main text of your solution that your suggested solution doesn't cover that aspect of the behavior that his current approach would (i.e. using `.save()` vice `findOneAndUpdate()`).  I didn't downvote you for using an extra module; you made no mention of it in your solution.

Comment: @Paul Point duly noted. Let me make the changes.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the only way, but I use the Lodash library to make this kind of thing easy. I also use the 'param' route to populate the request with my object for me to save callbacks.

```
const _= require("lodash ")
router.param("teacherId", function(id, req,res,next){
   Teacher.findOne({_id : id}, function(e, teacher){ 
        //add error handling of your choice
        req.teacher = teacher;
        next();
   })
})


router.put("teacher/:teacherId", function(req,res){
   var updates = _.pick(req.body, ["name","age"]; // whitelist allowed attribute names to change

   var teacher = _.merge(req.teacher, updates);
   teacher.save(function(e){
      // handle your response. 
   })
})
```

/* Edit */

Also, please note that in this solution, I'm assuming the use of (reasonably standard) REST-formatted routes.  If you want to keep using `router.post('/update'...` that's fine, but you won't be able to separate out the teacher query like I did.

The advantage of the way I did it is that anytime you want to find a thing first (e.g. viewing a teacher, deleting a teacher, etc), you have the logic for doing so in one place, and don't have to repeat it in other handlers.